# Help - Incorrect reading of magnetic encoder

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-2

I am a beginner having trouble to read a magnetic encoder. I have found the following code I found that I am using in order to read the encoder values:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio

class decoder:

   """Class to decode mechanical rotary encoder pulses."""

   def __init__(self, pi, gpioA, gpioB, callback):

      """
      Instantiate the class with the pi and gpios connected to
      rotary encoder contacts A and B.  The common contact
      should be connected to ground.  The callback is
      called when the rotary encoder is turned.  It takes
      one parameter which is +1 for clockwise and -1 for
      counterclockwise.

      EXAMPLE

      import time
      import pigpio

      import rotary_encoder

      pos = 0

      def callback(way):

         global pos

         pos += way

         print("pos={}".format(pos))

      pi = pigpio.pi()

      decoder = rotary_encoder.decoder(pi, 7, 8, callback)

      time.sleep(300)

      decoder.cancel()

      pi.stop()

      """

      self.pi = pi
      self.gpioA = gpioA
      self.gpioB = gpioB
      self.callback = callback

      self.levA = 0
      self.levB = 0

      self.lastGpio = None

      self.pi.set_mode(gpioA, pigpio.INPUT)
      self.pi.set_mode(gpioB, pigpio.INPUT)

      self.pi.set_pull_up_down(gpioA, pigpio.PUD_UP)
      self.pi.set_pull_up_down(gpioB, pigpio.PUD_UP)

      self.cbA = self.pi.callback(gpioA, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, self._pulse)
      self.cbB = self.pi.callback(gpioB, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, self._pulse)

   def _pulse(self, gpio, level, tick):

      """
      Decode the rotary encoder pulse.

                   +---------+         +---------+      0
                   |         |         |         |
         A         |         |         |         |
                   |         |         |         |
         +---------+         +---------+         +----- 1

             +---------+         +---------+            0
             |         |         |         |
         B   |         |         |         |
             |         |         |         |
         ----+         +---------+         +---------+  1
      """

      if gpio == self.gpioA:
         self.levA = level
      else:
         self.levB = level;

      if gpio != self.lastGpio: # debounce
         self.lastGpio = gpio

         if   gpio == self.gpioA and level == 1:
            if self.levB == 1:
               self.callback(1)
         elif gpio == self.gpioB and level == 1:
            if self.levA == 1:
               self.callback(-1)

   def cancel(self):

      """
      Cancel the rotary encoder decoder.
      """

      self.cbA.cancel()
      self.cbB.cancel()

if __name__ == "__main__":

   import time
   import pigpio

   import rotary_encoder

   pos = 0

   def callback(way):

      global pos

      pos += way

      print("pos={}".format(pos))

   pi = pigpio.pi()

   decoder = rotary_encoder.decoder(pi, 7, 8, callback)

   time.sleep(300)

   decoder.cancel()

   pi.stop()
```

However when I run this code I do get pos values but they are incorrect the encoders I am using are:
encoders: https://www.pololu.com/product/3081
motors: https://didacticaselectronicas.com/index.php/elementos-electromecanicos/motores-y-solenoides-1/motores-dc-1/micro-motorreductor-hp-2981-100rpm-5kg-cm-ext-shaft-detail
I am aware to the fact this is a quiet high rpm motor, but I get readings of about 1000 per one revolution of the wheel when I should get (if my calculations are correct) 12 * 298. I tried using lower speeds of rotation, and also to print the reading only once at the end of the run but it is still much lower reading values than expected. Any ideas on how can I fix it or where I am wrong?
Post Reply

Comment: Are the readings consistent?  I.e. do you always get the same figure for one rotation?  What is the figure?

Comment: pretty much consistent because I use DC motor I cant do exactly 1 revolution but for one revolution of the wheel it is 1200 +-20. For time of rotating that I checked If I rotate for 3 seconds it was about 4000 and it repeated this result several times, and when it ran with half the speed it was 2000. So all in all the readings are consistent but incorrect. (I should get much higher values).

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the readings are correct and you have misunderstood the encoder/motor gearing.